# How to prevent the responsive behavior on a specific element when twitter bootstrap responsive.css is loaded?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

let's say I have a grid element :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span5">...</div>
</div>
```

[image: horizontally aligned divs]

When i am on a normal desktop screen `.span4` and `.span5` are horizontally aligned. However when the screen is smaller, let's say  phone both the divs get stacked up *'vertically'*

[image: horizontally aligned divs]

this is really great but i want to prevent this from happening on a specific div. It has enough space to keep the horizontal layout.

**Note**
There is always the possibility to create my own non responsive .span  (.myspan2, myspan4,...) but besides is there  **lazy solution to that**? i dont want to add 8 lines of code for one element in an entire project.

Answer (score 0):

You can write media queries to specific resolution for the div to arrange your layout . Like

```
    /* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { write your styles here  }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { write your styles here  }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { write your styles here  }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { write your styles here  }
```